# How to slice and dice this input dictionary and get the desired output dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = {
    "a": 30,
    "b": 45,
    "c": 84,
    "d": 92,
    "e": 93
    }
```

the story here is suppose i have a python list that has 93 items. the first 30 items (from index 0 to index 30) belongs to group "a", items from index 31 to index 45 belong to group "b". items from index 46 to index 84 belongs group "c". items from index 85 to index 92 belongs group "d". 93 rd item belongs to group "e".

so the above dictionary contains the last index of each group
from this dictionary I want to create a dictionary which should look like this:

```
final_d = {
    "a": [0, 30],
    "b": [31, 45],
    "c": [46, 84],
    "d": [85, 92],
    "e": [93]
}
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: How do you know that `0` should be the start of the range for `"a"`? Is that hard-coded? What if the values aren't sorted? Keep in mind that that in older versions of Python, dictionaries were not guaranteed to preserve order, and in fact were intended to be treated as not having any order. Even with modern Python, it doesn't make sense to put data like this into a dictionary unless you will actually look it up by key somewhere else in the program.

Comment: it is hard coded that the first index is 0

Comment: Also, why is the result for the `"e"` key `[93]`, and not `[93, 93]` (i.e., a range like all the others)? Do you want to collapse the values like this every time a range only has a single number? What if there aren't any numbers in the range (duplicate values in the dict)? Keep in mind how this might complicate the logic *elsewhere* in the code. `Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.`

Comment: Conceptually, I see the problem as having four parts: find the ascending values from the dictionary (for example, gathering them into a list); find the corresponding beginning points of the ranges (by making use of other values in the list); use the lists of bottom and top values to make ranges; and store the ranges back into the dictionary. Can you try to write code for each step? If you have an elegant way of doing each part, are you satisfied?

Comment: Beside the point, but your index numbers don't line up. I think when you say "from index 31 to index 45", you mean "from index **30** to index 45", etc. (which aligns with the element counts you wrote and slice notation).

Comment: What's `final_d` actually going to be used for? If you want to slice the list according to the groups, you don't need `final_d`, it'd just be an extra step. Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: Thanks for all this information. These were very useful and I have stepped back from the idea of creating the final dictionary this way. I can create the final dictionary without creating the intermediate dictionary ```d``` in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split in two list,keys and values, then put them in a zip function with both normal and shifted order.

```py
keys,values=list(d.keys()),list(d.values())
{key:[x+1,y] for key,x,y in zip(keys,[-1]+values[:-1],values)}
```

output:

```
{'a': [0, 30], 'b': [31, 45], 'c': [46, 84], 'd': [85, 92], 'e': [93, 93]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [x for x in range(93)]

d = {
    "a": 30,
    "b": 45,
    "c": 84,
    "d": 92,
    "e": 93
    }

s = 0
final_d = {}
final_data = {}
for index, value in d.items():
    e = value
    final_d[index] = [s+1,e]
    final_data[index] = data[s:e]
    s = e

print(final_d)
print(final_data)
```

Output:

```
{
 'a': [0, 30],
 'b': [31, 45],
 'c': [46, 84],
 'd': [85, 92],
 'e': [93, 93]
}

{
 'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
 'b': [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
 'c': [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83],
 'd': [84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91],
 'e': [92]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One elegant way to do is by using `pd.qcut`:

```
import pandas as pd    
max_num = d[max(d, key=d.get)]
ls = [v/max_num for _, v in d.items()]
ls.insert(0, 0)
A = pd.qcut(range(max_num + 1),
            ls, precision=10 ^ 5).categories.values
dict_ = {A[i] for i, _ in enumerate(d)}
```

Output:

```
dict_
{Interval(84.0, 92.0, closed='right'), Interval(-1e-15, 30.0, closed='right'), Interval(92.0, 93.0, closed='right'), Interval(45.0, 84.0, closed='right'), Interval(30.0, 45.0, closed='right')}
```